# java.lang.illegalargumentexception: wrong number of arguments

Tags: java, excepciones

Tengo el siguiente código de una clase que sumará dos números. [image: El un clase que sumará dos números].

Luego tengo el siguiente código de test.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me da como resultado un excepción como se muestra en la imagen.
¿Cual es el problema? Tengo todo en orden pero no logro encontrar el error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, el código debe estar en formato texto y no en imágenes de captura de pantalla. Es más fácil *copiar y pegar* el código que transcribirlo completo desde una imagen. Te invito a leer [Un fragmento de código vale más que mil imágenes… ¿cómo sensibilizar a los usuarios de ese principio?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2990/un-fragmento-de-c%c3%b3digo-vale-m%c3%a1s-que-mil-im%c3%a1genes-c%c3%b3mo-sensibilizar-a-los-usu/3976#3976). Saludos

Comment: Y por favor, puedes poner toda la traza del error para ver en qué línea da?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible que te sobre el `Calculator` en el constructor puesto que en el `@Parameters` estás devolviendo una lista de 3 campos cada uno

Prueba esto:

```
public CalculatorParametrizedTest(int first, int last, int expectedSum) {
```

Además el `Calculator` ya se está creando dentro del `@Before`

Comment: No, no digo que afecte a que Calculator se cree ahí. Lo que quería decir (igual no me lo expliqué bien) es que no es necesario pasarlo en el constructor porque ya se crea en el `@Before`

Answer (score 0):

Como dijo el usuario **@sergiomse** no deberías esperar un objeto de **Calculator** en el constructor de `CalculatorParametrizedTest`. El motivo de esto es que **@Parameters** antes de la ejecución del test va a invocar el constructor de la clase enviandole los parámetros que tiene definidos en el Array de objetos que creaste. En dicha coleccion hay 3 elementos declarados (los 3 **int**), pero tu constructor está esperando 4 parámetros (3 enteros y 1 de tipo **Calculator**).

Dicho esto, el error retornado debería hacerte mas sentido: *java.lang.illegalargumentexception: wrong number of arguments*. Traducido: *excepcion en los argumentos de entrada: error en la cantidad de argumentos*

Desconstruyendo un poco mas mi respuesta paso a paso al momento de correr los test:

1. Como el test corre con `Parametrized.class` (definido en el **@RunWith** de la clase) lo primero que se hace es buscar el método con el tag `@Parameters` que sería **data()** y ejecutarlo, obteniendo así una lista de valores.
2. Luego por cada varlo devuelto correrá un test. Toma el primer elemento, que serán los parametros para todos los test definidos, en este caso {10, 10, 20} ; luego invoca al constructor de la clase enviando cada campo del elemento como parametro.
3. En el constructor: los primeros 3 enteros se asignan a **firt**, **second** y **expectedSum**, pero está faltando asignar un valor a **calculator**

### CONCLUSION

O se saca parametro **Calculator** de `CalculatorParametrizedTest`, o se agrega un objeto de tipo **Calculator** en cada elemente definido en el método **data()**. Lo ideal es resolver con la primera opcion.

Comment: Gracias estimado. Pude solucionar el problema.

Comment: Entonces marca la respuesta como acepatada!

Comment: @Pablo Me alegro que se haya solucionado y como dijo Benito-B acepta una respuesta para que se de por cerrada la pregunta. De esta forma no aparece la pregunta para responder y si alguien entra a esta, respondera sabiendo que esta resuelta. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Estimados logré resolver es el problema con vuestras respuestas. Muchas gracias. Quisiera mostrar la solución:

```
package main;

public class Calculator {
    
    private int firt;
    
    private int last;
    
    public Calculator(int firt, int last) {
        this.firt = firt;
        this.last = last;
    }
    
    public int sum() {
        return this.firt + this.last;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + this.sum() + "";
    }
}


package tests;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

import main.Calculator;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class CalculatorParametrizedTest {
    
    private int firt;
    
    private int last;
    
    private int expectedSum;
    
    private Calculator calculator;
    
    public CalculatorParametrizedTest(int firt, int last, int expectedSum) {
        this.firt = firt;
        this.last = last;
        this.expectedSum = expectedSum;
    }
    
    @Before
    public void before() {
        this.calculator = new Calculator(this.firt, this.last);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testSum() {
        assertEquals(this.expectedSum, this.calculator.sum());
    }
   
    @Parameters(name = " {0} + {1} = {2} ") 
    public static Iterable<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList( new Object[][] {{5,10, 15}, {1, 5, 6}});
    }
}
```

Esta es una forma mucho más compacta para eliminar el constructor horroroso.

```
package tests;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameter;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

import main.Calculator;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class CalculatorParametrizedTest {
    
    @Parameter(0)
    public int firt;
    
    @Parameter(1)
    public int last;
    
    @Parameter(2)
    public int expectedSum;
    
    private Calculator calculator;
        
    @Before
    public void before() {
        this.calculator = new Calculator(this.firt, this.last);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testSum() {
        assertEquals(this.expectedSum, this.calculator.sum());
    }
   
    @Parameters(name = " {0} + {1} = {2} ") 
    public static Iterable<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList( new Object[][] {{5,10, 15}, {1, 5, 6}});
    }
}
```

Comment: No olvides marcar como aceptada aquella respuesta que fue la solución